# Npgsql PostgisMultiPolygon entity type configuration Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, postgis, npgsql

I have a postgis table named cities

```
public class City{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PostgisMultiPolygon Geometry { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use Entity Framework to get data. And I created an entity type configuration like this.

```
public class MyConvention : EntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    public MyConvention()
    {
        ToTable("cities", "public");

        Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("gid");
        Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("name");
        Property(p => p.Geometry).HasColumnName("geom");
    }
}
```

But Geometry property throws error.

> The type 'NpgsqlTypes.PostgisMultiPolygon' must be a non-nullable
>   value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or
>   method
>   'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration.Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'

If I remove the convention, and set property name same as database column name.

```
public class City{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PostgisMultiPolygon geom { get; set; }
}
```

throws an other error:

> (6,10) : error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line
>   6:No mapping specified for properties City.geom in Set Cities. An
>   Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:   Entity is type
>   [PostgisEntityFramework.City]

Comment: If you remove the convention does everything work? In other words, is the problem exclusively with Property()?

Comment: I updated the post removed convention

Comment: Can you confirm you're in EF 6.x (not core)? I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think EF 6.x will support the custom PostGIS types. You'll have to look at DbGeometry instead, which should be supported (but may not provide what you want). EF Core should support the Postgis* types natively.

Comment: My reference versions are like this: **EF 6.0, EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.1.1.0 and Npgsql 3.1.9.0**

Comment: When I used `DBGeometry type` the error is changed: **Not supported edm type: Edm.Geometry**

Comment: Hi, So finally how did you do this?